# What is the name of the face that appears in this list of company completions?

Tags: faces, company-mode, help

If I have company-mode enabled, and I type in company like this.

```
(company)
```

I then see a list of completions that I can select. My question is - apart from the currently selected item, the word company is highlighted differently and I'm trying to figure out the name of the face that's at work here. I've circled one example in red.

[image: popup of candidate completions from company]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't put your cursor on a character that has the face (which I'm guessing is the case for a Company popup menu), then use **`M-x list-faces-display`**.

That shows you all of the currently defined faces - what they look like - with links to customizing them.

You can usually tell by the appearance of a face and looking for its name (e.g. `company-` something) which face it is.

---

If you *can* put your cursor on a character that has the face, then do that and use `C-u C-x =`. Near its bottom, the `*Help*` buffer tells all of the faces used on that character.

Comment: The two faces are company-tooltip-common and company-tooltip-common-selection.

Comment: You can use `M-x customize-face` to change the appearance of any face.

Answer (score 2):

With *Emacs*, it's common to have different ways for achieving the same goal. Identification of a face shown in an *overlayed tooltip* by `company-mode` is no different. The list of some of the approaches follow, starting with the most straightforward (subjectively) solutions.

#### Consult User Manual

[`company-mode` user manual](https://company-mode.github.io/manual/Frontends.html#Faces) -- or <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(info "(company) Tooltip Frontends")` -- lists *tooltip frontend* faces and a sample screenshot. This information allows to identify the questioned face as `company-tooltip-common`.

#### Command `list-faces-display`

[*Emacs* documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html#Faces) -- or <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(emacs) Faces")` -- suggests:

> To see what faces are currently defined, and what they look like, type
> `M-x list-faces-display`. With a prefix argument, this prompts for a
> regular expression, and displays only faces with names matching that
> regular expression

Note the latter phrase. It means that *company-mode* faces can be reviewed by entering

`C-u M-x list-faces-display` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^company`.

This lists `company-mode` faces names and samples in `*Faces*` buffer.

[image: company-mode faces listed in Faces buffer]

Note the help text at the top of the buffer. Basically, it means: click the face's name or sample for its customization.

#### Command `customize-apropos-faces`

`M-x customize-apropos-faces` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^company` opens `*Customize Apropos*` buffer, with smaller samples and also direct access to face customization.

[image: company-mode faces listed in *Customize Apropos* buffer]

#### Command `describe-face`

This command might be somewhat usable in the case discussed, but only with additional conditions met (such as `fido-mode` enabled, f.i.).

By default, `M-x describe-face` displays properties of a face after *point* (aka *cursor*), so we'd have to manually cycle through all the `company-*` faces to review/customize them all one by one in `*Help*` buffer, like this:

`M-x describe-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> `company-` <kbd>C-s</kbd>

[image: describe-face with fido-mode enabled]

[image: company-mode face properties in *Help* buffer]

#### Lookup in Source (going wild, why not)

There're many ways to find faces definitions in source files.
For example, open `~/path/to/company/source/company.el` and call `M-x occur`:

`M-s o` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^(defface company` <kbd>RET</kbd>

This will list all the faces definitions in `*Occur*` buffer. Navigate with <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> to open / review each face definition.
[image: company-mode faces via *Occur* buffer]