# what is that face used for ... completion

Tags: faces, company

I try to customize the face  for the part showing "company" which is not in a blueish background part. In the picture it is on a light milky background with a kind of gold foreground.  I've searched among all the company.. face but did not find.
Thk.
I use these packages:

> company, company-go, company-capf, company-tabnine

[image: Company selection]

Comment: Try `M-x customize-apropos-faces RET ^company RET` or `M-x customize-group RET company-faces`, and go by the clues offered by the `customize` widget.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the name of the face that appears in this list of company completions?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69894/what-is-the-name-of-the-face-that-appears-in-this-list-of-company-completions)

Comment: Thank, was very helpfull